# ng-grid filterOptions blank filterText does not work in IE8

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

When I set `filterOptions.filterText = 'category : ' + filteringText` , I don't see any rows when `filteringText` is blank. However if `filteringText` is not blank, then this filter works.

Here is preview in [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/OYkiD2/preview)

This is an issue only with IE8. Any way to fix this ?

To duplicate the issue, download this as a zip file and run in IE8.  Check box '`All`' which is supposed to show all the rows, hides all of them. 
(The preview link I gave above, does not work in IE8 so you have to download the plunk and open the index.html file. Thanks IE8)

Comment: Can anyone let me know if I can add OR condition. So instead of setting filteringText to blank, I will check for all possible values with an OR condition to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like ie8 passes *undefined* to ng-model for an empty string.

Since your ngmodel directive binds filteringText

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="filteringText" value="" /> All
```

and you watch this to actually set the filterText after that, try changing your code to this

```
$scope.$watch('filteringText',function(newVal){
    if ((newVal === '') || (typeof newVal == 'undefined')) {
        $scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText = '';
    }
    else
      $scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText = 'category : ' + newVal;
});
```

I briefly tested and seems to work in both IE8 and chrome v30

Comment: I confirmed this works in IE8. I should have checked the newVal value when I clicked on Add. Thanks so much.